# SQL Server how to get Count of a field for the current Quarter from Date?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a hard time assembling a SQL statement. The scenario/requirement is like this: I need to get a count of a field in a current quarter.

```
SELECT COUNT(fieldname) AS Hits 
FROM tablename 
WHERE DatePosted = (Current Quarter)
```

I would like to get the no of Hits/Count for current quarter.

Is this possible?

Comment: how is current quarter defined? is it four quater in a year?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select count(fieldname) as Hits 
from tablename
where datepart(q,DatePosted) = datepart(q,getdate())
and year(DatePosted) = year(getdate())
```

Comment: +1 For using the build-in options. A lot of times, we are "Reinventing the wheel".